# How does custom serializer affect searching?

Tags: c#, mongodb, nodatime

I am trying to use [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) in my app. The app persists data in a mongodb database. Consider the following class

```
public class SomeType
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public Instant Instant { get; set; }
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
    public DateTime DateTimeUtc { get; set; }
//    public ZonedDateTime ZonedDateTime { get; set; }
//    public LocalDateTime LocalDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Without adding a custom serializer, the `Instant` property of the class doesn't get stored in the db. Reading the document from the db also fails.

```
public class InstantBsonSerializer : BsonBaseSerializer
{
    public override object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        var ticks = bsonReader.ReadInt64();
        return new Instant(ticks);
    }

    public override object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        var ticks = bsonReader.ReadInt64();
        return new Instant(ticks);
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        var instant = (Instant) value;
        bsonWriter.WriteInt64(instant.Ticks);
    }
}
```

I created the above serializer and registered it properly. I am now able to save and retrieve instances of my class with the proper value set for `Instant`.

My question is how does the C# driver handle searching using linq?

```
var list = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<SomeType>("SomeType")
                     .AsQueryable<SomeType>()
                     .Where(x => x.Instant < Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(dateTime.ToUniversalTime()))
                     .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
```

I get the correct list of documents. **I am trying to understand HOW mongodb gets this data. Does it first load ALL data, deserialize it properly and then filter? Or does it serialize the `Instant` value of the where clause and use the serialized value to filter all documents, load matching ones and then deserialize?**

*I tried seeing the query logged by the mongodb profiler, but its doesnt seem to log anything. I have set the profiling level to 2.*

In the case of `Instant` the serialized value is a `long`. But in case of `ZonedDateTime`, the serialized value will be a document with two properties. How will searching work in that case?

**Edit:**

I was able to get the profiling to work. The following c# query,

```
mongoDatabase.GetCollection<SomeType>("SomeTypeCollection")
             .AsQueryable<SomeType>()
             .Where(x => x.Instant < Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.UtcNow))
             .ToList();
```

results in the following mongodb query

```
{ "Instant": { $lt: 13781017828460782 }}
```

Meaning, the c# driver serializes my `Instant` object and uses the serialized value to filter the results in the db itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver will convert you linq query into a mongodb query and filter results before deserialising them.  The query will not run until you call `ToList()`

Here are the operators that are supported: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/

The custom deserialiser will not come into play until the driver starts building the object graph from the data returned.

You wouldn't normally need a custom serialiser for classes with simple types or where you're not doing extra work when reading/writing the docs.

If you wanted to control what was serialised, ie if essentially your class holds a single  datetime, why not make it so that the UTC datetime stamp is stored and use `BsonIgnore` for the other properties.

Comment: But the filter clause makes use of a class that needs a custom serializer. How is mongodb able to create a mongo-query out of it? If I were to write it as a mongo-query I would pass a `bson object` as the value for the `$lt` operator. But how does the c# driver represent my custom serialized class as a bson object?

Comment: From what i understand the driver will use reflection to establish the attribute names to compile the query so `var res = mongodb.GetCollection("MyColl").AsQueryable<MyColl>().Where(x=>x.Prop == 123)` would compile a query of `{Prop:{$eq:123}}` or `{ Prop:123 }` - using BsonElement attribute can control the name of the attribute when serialising and querying.  Once the query is returned the driver will deserialise the BsonDocument into an object. A default class map used for this class will be used if you use the default serialiser.

Comment: it's worth noting that you can query the database passing in a BsonDocument for the query, returning a cursor which you iterate through returning a BsonDocument for each result.  Individually each can be deserialised into the C# POCO object. If there is a custom serialiser registered for a specific type, it will be used to hydrate  the object.